# DRF Updating an existing model after adding values to non existing fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a bet app so that user can create bet and challenge other . But I am unable to create a new bet since I am placing the user who accepted the bet on the same model instance:
this is how my model looking like .

```
class CreateBet(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="bets",null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bet_name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    scheduled_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    accepted_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,related_name="accept",null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

so what I want is whenever I hit:

```
router.register('api/bets',BetViewset,'userbets')
```

this end point I want user to create a bet without adding to fields `accepted_user` and `status` . But if the user hit:

```
router.register('accept_bet',AcceptBetViewset,'accept')
```

this end point both the `accepted_user` will be created and `status` will be set to `True`.
currently my serializer looking like this

```
class BetCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta :
        model = CreateBet
        exclude = ['accepted_user','status']
```

and its api:

```
class BetViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]
    serializer_class = BetCreateSerializer
    
    def perform_create(self,serializer):
        serializer.save(owner = self.request.user)
    

    def get_queryset(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        return CreateBet.objects.filter(scheduled_datetime__date=today)
```

which works perfectly fine .

but whenever I tried with this serializer :

```
class AcceptBetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bet = BetCreateSerializer(many = True , read_only= True)
    class Meta:
        model = CreateBet
        fields ='__all__'
        # def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        #     id = validated_data.pop('id')
        #     object = CreateBet.objects.get(id=id)
        #     object.save(status=True)
```

and with this viewset:

```
class AcceptBetViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):


    serializer_class = AcceptBetSerializer


    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    
    
    
    def perform_create(self,serializer):
        print('hii')
        serializer.save(accepted_user = self.request.user,status=True)
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return CreateBet.objects.filter(accepted_user=self.request.user)
```

not working the way as I expected . whenever I try to accept the bet, instead it updates to existing field it is creating a new bet object with null field values for `owner`,`bet_name`,`amount` and `scheduled_date`. I tried everything with my limited knowledge .Does anyone have some suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically it sounds like you want to create instances of `CreateBet` and then later post updates to the instance?

I think you are on the right lines, but I think your code could be simpler than it is.

My suggestion would be to work through the [DRF tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/), and then the documentation, and get a firm understanding of how it fits together.  It will save you a lot of time in the long run rather than trying to get SO users to work it out for you.

Comment: Hagarty ,yah! You are right . I spent my whole day working with this one . But, unfortunately I am unable to do it